# Change the number of columns in GridView With Zoom / Pinch

Tags: android, gridview, pinchzoom

In my application I implemented a Gallery like view using GridView. I want to change the number of columns in GridView manually as per user's choice. I can change it by providing any button or menu option. I want to do same thing with Zoom / Pinch operation like, if some one tries to zoom the GridView, it should reduce the number of columns and increase the same if tries to Pinch. To achieve this I tried overriding onTouch event but its neither smooth nor as desired. If any one knows or have any idea of how to achieve this please let me know.

Comment: hi suresh, i am also working on the same requirement as this . did you implemented it ? if yes could you pls post a sample code here or my mail? it will be really helpfull

Answer (score 0):

This won't be easy.

First I would try this:

Put a plain View on top of the GridView (i.e. this View is at the same position as GridView and has the same width and height).

Override the onTouchEvent of this plain View. If you detect a Pinch Zoom do the special handling (changing the GridView's columns). If you don't detect a Pinch Zoom, let the onTouchEvent return false (not handled) letting the touch-events bubble down to the underlying GridView.

The trick is in recognizing a Pinch Zoom correctly and not messing up the default touch behavior of the GridView.